# Nvidia GPU heats up on idle on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating

I have a MSI gs65 8sf laptop with ubuntu 19.04 and the latest driver of the nvidia.

My problem is that when the Nvidia GPU is in idle (e.g. when I switch on intel with `prime-select`or when I lock the screen) it starts to heat up around 55 °C.

The normal temperature for the GPU when is active (e.g. when I'm writing this question) is around 42°C/48°C.

UEFI and Firmware are already updated at the last version.

The nvidia driver version is 418.56.

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found the solution asking on a nvidia forum. [This](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1063156/linux/geforce-rtx-2070-maxq-heats-up-when-in-idle-on-msi-gs65-8sf-with-ubuntu-19-04-and-nvidia-driver-430-40/) is the thread with the answer, I'm going to make a recap of the solution here.

#### Recap

The problem is that the prime-select program does not turn off the GPU when it offload the drivers. So when you switch on the intel profile the nvidia driver are offloaded and all the power management stuff with them, but the GPU is on, this causes the heating up process.

#### Solution

The solution that I've found is: Install bbswitch with apt. 
This program will automatically turn off the GPU if the drivers are not loaded.

So when you want to switch to the intel profile:

- select the intel profile `# prime-select intel`
- reboot the pc.

at the next boot the drivers for the nvidia won't be loaded and bbswitch will turn off the GPU, if you want to use the nvidia GPU do the same thing: select the nvidia profile and reboot.